# Azure: Create EventHub programmatically JAVA

Tags: java, azure, cloud, scale, azure-eventhub

I develop a high load enterprise application. 
There are 2 services which should be scaled in specific way. They use Azure EventHubs for messaging. When load increase we need to create one more instance of a service and create one more topic (Event Hub) for communication with other services.

Is there a way to create event hub dynamically from java code? For example if I use Kafka I can just pass name of topic that doesn't exist and it will create it by itself. When I try to do it with Azure EventHubs I have such error:

```
The messaging entity 'sb://eventhubdev.servicebus.windows.net/newTopic' could not be found.
```

So... is it possible to create and delete it programmatically?
Google didn't help me with this question clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation we decided to create new topic by direct API calls as described in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs/createorupdate

Answer (score 0):

There might be a solution to scale via java, but I would challenge that. 
Scaling should be handled by your infrastructure (e.g. kubernetes) and not your code.
Furthermore, I don't know if the eventhub is dynamically enough to be scaled in the first place.

Providing the eventhub could be done via terraform. 
See Link for further details:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/eventhub.html